# How do I get System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting dll into WebMatrix 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-webpages, webmatrix-3

I want to use the full charting options available in ASP.NET Web Pages in WebMatrix 3.

I think this means using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

When adding:

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting
```

to the top of my page, I get the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

There are plenty of tutorials out there (including on SO) demonstrating how to download and reference the dll into Visual Studio, but as far as I can see there's nothing for us WebMatrix users.

Does this mean that it can't be used in a WebMatrix site? If so, why??

If anyone knows how to include the relevant namespace in WM, I'd be very grateful if you'd explain it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMatrix doesn't provide a mechanism for adding references. However, you can work around this by right clicking on the *bin* folder and choosing `Add Existing File`. Then you need to locate `System.Web.Datavizualization.dll`, which on my machine is located in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319. Once you have a copy of that dll in your bin folder, you are in business.

I would however recommend moving across to Visual Studio. Then it's simply a case of using File » Open » Web Site to open your WebMatrix site folder.